# Weird IllegalArgumentException in Calendar.getTime()

Tags: java, calendar

This perfectly simple test fails with `IllegalArgumentException("HOUR_OF_DAY 2 -> 3")`, and I see no reason why. You can change any of the hours, days, months, years to any other value and the test succeeds. Fails in any of the JRE's I tested on. Seems to be an internal problem in the GregorgianCalendar implementation? Or am I missing something obvious?

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DateTest extends TestCase
{
    /** test if 2011/03/27 02:30:00 converts to a valid date.
     * shouldn't throw any exception, however this throws 
     * IllegalArgumentException("HOUR_OF_DAY 2 -> 3)
     */
    @Test
    public void testDate()
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setLenient(false);
        cal.clear();
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 02);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 27);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 03 - 1); // needs to be 0-based
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2011);
        cal.getTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: it fails identically when using `cal.set(2011, 03 - 1, 27, 02, 30, 00);`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This date and time combination doesn't exist in your timezone, because it falls into discontinuity caused by daylight savings.

Since you configured `setLenient(false)`, `Calendar` correctly throws an exception when you try to enter a non-existing date.

A rule of thumb: if you see something weird in date and time calculations, suspect daylight savings.

Comment: Right. Now the error message "2 -> 3" makes sense as well. Thanks.