# Error : SqlExceptionHelper : HOUR_OF_DAY: 2 -> 3

Tags: java, mysql, spring, date, calendar

Full error log:

> 2019-09-20 08:35:37.860  INFO 1 --- [nio-8081-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat-1].[localhost].[/]     : Initializing Spring
>   DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
>
> 2019-09-20 08:47:29.726 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8081-exec-5]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : HOUR_OF_DAY: 2 -> 3
>
> 2019-09-20 08:47:29.769 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8081-exec-5]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute
>   query; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query]
>   with root cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 2 -> 3
>
> at java.base/java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:na]
>
> at java.base/java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>
> at java.base/java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:na]

This problem has been solved at [Java level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351680/weird-illegalargumentexception-in-calendar-gettime), but how do I avoid it at *mysql* level.

In fact the query does not even have date or time.

```
@Query("select o from Order o where o.tickets is not null")
List<Order> ordersWithExistingTickets();
```

---

#### EDIT 1:

Order.java

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="orders")
public class Order {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "PK")
private Long pk;

@Column(name = "createdTS")
private ZonedDateTime creationTime;

@Column(name = "tickets")
private String tickets;

public String getTickets() {
    return tickets;
}

public void setTickets(String tickets) {
    this.tickets = tickets;
}}
```

---

#### EDIT 2:

OrderRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {

    @Query("select o from Order o where o.tickets is not null")
    List<Order> ordersWithExistingTickets();
}
```

Comment: Does `Order` have a date/time field? Maybe a computated column? What is the query that is actually executed?

Comment: yes...`Order` has many date/time fields

Comment: I'm not sure if you can fix this on mysql level, since parameters are supplied by your application.

Comment: Which hibernate version do you use? It could very well be that your version is too old for java 8 support

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` - this is not even an sql exception, `HOUR_OF_DAY` - this only exists in your java code, not in mysql. Again, not sure what you want to do about this in mysql.

Comment: @Shadow : It is indeed calling Java files, but I am getting the error when I am hitting the query in repository (edit 2)

Comment: That still does not mean that the error comes from and therefore can be prevented at mysql level. Nothing of the exception details indicate that this has anything to do with mysql. You really need to debug your code and **data** (invalid datetime data in mysql?) to understand where things go south. This is the drawback of using ORMs - you do not really know what gets executed.

Comment: @Shadow: Yes, but this is all the java code that I have....so can you please suggest something I can add before calling the query method....something like.... `cal.setLenient(true)`

Comment: Nope, cannot suggest anything. I only know mysql, but not java. If you want a solution in mysql, you need to identify what causes the issue in mysql - if anything.

Comment: It’s thrown from the line `throw new IllegalArgumentException(getFieldName(field) + ": " + s);` near the end of `GregorianCalendar.computeTime()`. It’s aome validation message, but I don’t understand what exactly it means nor why it happens.

Comment: By the way, a creation moment should be tracked as an `Instant` generally, or as a `OffsetDateTime` when retrieved via JDBC 4.2+, not a `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is there's a date time field (not timestamp) that is not available in your timezone.  So it can't convert it correctly.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 2 -> 3
> at java.base/java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2826)
> at java.base/java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:3428)
> at java.base/java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1812)
> at com.mysql.cj.result.SqlTimestampValueFactory.localCreateFromTimestamp(SqlTimestampValueFactory.java:108)

There's information on https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/illegalargumentexception-hour_of_day-after-changing-mysql-database-timezone-1063564762.html

but generally you have to locate the errant record and remove or update it from the database.

Assuming you're using JOOQ or have access to do it (as using the JPA query will cause issues).  Here's a code snippet I put in my JUnit Integration test

```java
@Test
void ensureDatesAreOkayDuringDaylightSavings() {
  var fallbackDayClauses = IntStream
    .range(2000, LocalDate.now().getYear() + 1)
    .mapToObj(year ->
      LocalDate.ofYearDay(year, 1)
        .withMonth(3)
        .with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY))
        .with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY))
        .atTime(1, 59, 0)
    )
    .map(startDateTime -> 
        MYDB.CREATED_ON.between(
          startDateTime, 
          startDateTime
            .plusHours(1)
            .plusMinutes(2)))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

  var potentialProblemIds = dsl.select(MYDB.ID)
    .from(MYDB.TABLE)
    .where(or(fallbackDayClauses))
    .fetch(MYDB.ID);

  assertThat(potentialProblemIds)
    .isEmpty();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We faced similar issues after migration from MySQL 5 to MySQL 8 connector. Verified following links

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/illegalargumentexception-hour_of_day-1063564762.html
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=96276
https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2863969_1.html

Issue Case Query: When both Database and Java application in 'US/Pacific' timezone.

SELECT actiondoneon FROM likes WHERE actiondoneon BETWEEN '2019-03-10 02:00:00' AND '2019-03-10 03:00:00';

+---------------------+

| actiondoneon        |

+---------------------+

| 2019-03-10 02:27:47 |

+---------------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Fix Case Query:

mysql> SELECT convert_tz(actiondoneon, 'US/Pacific', 'US/Pacific') AS actiondoneon FROM likes WHERE actiondoneon BETWEEN '2019-03-10 02:00:00' AND '2019-03-10 03:00:00';

+---------------------+

| actiondoneon        |

+---------------------+

| 2019-03-10 03:00:00 |

+---------------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Here we are applying convert_tz with the same time zone. Convert_tz function is rounding off to the nearest correct timestamp.

Example :

mysql> SELECT invalid_timestamp, convert_tz(invalid_timestamp, 'US/Pacific', 'US/Pacific') corrcted_timestamp FROM (SELECT '2019-03-10 02:27:47' invalid_timestamp) tab;

+---------------------+----------------------------+

| invalid_timestamp   | corrcted_timestamp         |

+---------------------+----------------------------+

| 2019-03-10 02:27:47 | 2019-03-10 03:00:00.000000 |

+---------------------+----------------------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Answer (score 0):

I tried suggestions here, and various other places. Nothing worked out.
I had to set the MySQL server time to UTC. Followed the steps mentioned here -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html
Ensure you pay attention to the section "Populating the Time Zone Tables" which actually was the issue we were facing.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34868690)